# How do I delete an item from Core Data that has a specific attribute?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm writing an iOS app which utilizes Core Data (NSManagedObject, NSManagedObjectContext..etc) and I was wondering if there is a way to delete an object from the database that meets specific criteria.  For example, suppose I have a database of "Form" entities. Is there a fast way to delete the form whose attribute `name` is equal to, say, the word @"Untitled".  I know that I could fetch the object and then use `- (void)deleteObject:(NSManagedObject *)object` method of `NSManagedObjectContext` but this seems like it would be extremely slow to fetch an entire entity into memory just so that we can turn around and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you actually do have to fetch objects that you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call delete on the object itself. Otherwise if you could do the way you suggested and there are several objects that also have their name equal to @"Untitled" Core Data would not know which object/row you want to delete.